# Resources.getSystem().getInteger(android.R.attr.state_expanded) throws NotFoundException

Tags: android, android-resources

I am trying to fiddle with the group indicator and therefore used parts of the source for the ExpandableListView. I have this line of code:

```
/** State indicating the group is expanded and empty (has no children). */
    private static final int[] GROUP_EXPANDED_EMPTY_STATE_SET =
            {Resources.getSystem().getInteger(android.R.attr.state_expanded), Resources.getSystem().getInteger(android.R.attr.state_empty)};
```

but this always throws an NotFoundException. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the same declaration on a non-static constant?

Comment: yep.. still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to simply use:

```
 /** State indicating the group is expanded and empty (has no children). */
    private static final int[] GROUP_EXPANDED_EMPTY_STATE_SET =
            {android.R.attr.state_expanded, android.R.attr.state_empty};
```

you do not need the Ressources.getSystem() part

Comment: That only adds the resource identifier in the array. not the values that those resource ids reference.